# AWS SDK for iOS didFailWithError not called when exceptions are off

Tags: iphone, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

when I setup my S3 like that

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) S3TransferManager *tm;

.
.

[AmazonErrorHandler shouldNotThrowExceptions];
[AmazonLogger verboseLogging];
self.tm = [S3TransferManager new];
self.tm.s3 = self.s3;
self.tm.delegate = self;
```

and then use

```
request = .......

S3TransferOperation * op = [self.tm download:request];
```

when I fetch a file that exists on my S3 account, the callback gets called fine

```
-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didCompleteWithResponse:(AmazonServiceResponse *)response
```

but when I try to fetch a file that does not exits, the callback does not get called

```
-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

if I remove

```
// [AmazonErrorHandler shouldNotThrowExceptions];
```

then I have a different problem, the exception is thrown, but despite me having a proper @try..@catch block in place, the app crashes

```
    @try {

        .
        .
        .
        S3TransferOperation * op = [self.tm download:request];

    } @catch (AmazonServiceException *exception) {

        NSLog(@"========================>[S3 Module] ERROR, Unable to download file : %@", exception.error);

        return NUMBOOL(NO);

    } @catch (NSException * exception) {

        NSLog(@"*************************[S3 Module] ERROR, Unable to download file : %@", exception);

        return NUMBOOL(NO);
    }
```

this is the AWS SDK verbose log when exception throwing is disabled

```
    [DEBUG] 2013-12-01 23:25:16.243 Ti-AWS-S3[84675:a0b] AmazonS3Client.m|-[AmazonS3Client invoke:]|443|Begin Request: S3GetObjectMetadataRequest
    [DEBUG] 2013-12-01 23:25:16.246 Ti-AWS-S3[84675:a0b] AmazonS3Client.m|-[AmazonS3Client signS3Request:]|646|In SignURLRequest: String to Sign = [HEAD
    [DEBUG] application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
    [DEBUG] Sun, 01 Dec 2013 21:25:16 GMT
    [DEBUG] /hello-XXX/NDAb.pdf]
    [DEBUG] 2013-12-01 23:25:16.247 Ti-AWS-S3[84675:a0b] AmazonS3Client.m|-[AmazonS3Client invoke:]|462|HEAD https://hello-XXX.s3.amazonaws.com/NDAb.pdf?
    [DEBUG] 2013-12-01 23:25:16.248 Ti-AWS-S3[84675:a0b] AmazonS3Client.m|-[AmazonS3Client invoke:]|463|Request headers:
    [DEBUG] 2013-12-01 23:25:16.249 Ti-AWS-S3[84675:a0b] AmazonS3Client.m|-[AmazonS3Client invoke:]|466|  Date: Sun, 01 Dec 2013 21:25:16 GMT
    [DEBUG] 2013-12-01 23:25:16.250 Ti-AWS-S3[84675:a0b] AmazonS3Client.m|-[AmazonS3Client invoke:]|466|  Content-Length: 0
    [DEBUG] 2013-12-01 23:25:16.250 Ti-AWS-S3[84675:a0b] AmazonS3Client.m|-[AmazonS3Client invoke:]|466|  Authorization: AWS AKXXXXXW3YSTRRZAR4JPA:XXXXSAWELv5xAAR/mxXXXXVVJ2tr=
    [DEBUG] 2013-12-01 23:25:16.251 Ti-AWS-S3[84675:a0b] AmazonS3Client.m|-[AmazonS3Client invoke:]|466|  User-Agent: Transfer Manager, aws-sdk-iOS/1.7.0 iPhone-OS/7.0 en_US NE
    [DEBUG] 2013-12-01 23:25:16.252 Ti-AWS-S3[84675:a0b] AmazonS3Client.m|-[AmazonS3Client invoke:]|466|  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
    [DEBUG] 2013-12-01 23:25:16.252 Ti-AWS-S3[84675:a0b] AmazonS3Client.m|-[AmazonS3Client invoke:]|466|  Host: hello-XXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com
    [DEBUG] 2013-12-01 23:25:16.253 Ti-AWS-S3[84675:a0b] AmazonS3Client.m|-[AmazonS3Client invoke:]|468|Request body:
    [DEBUG] 2013-12-01 23:25:16.254 Ti-AWS-S3[84675:a0b] AmazonS3Client.m|-[AmazonS3Client invoke:]|470|
    [DEBUG] 2013-12-01 23:25:17.840 Ti-AWS-S3[84675:a0b] S3Response.m|-[S3Response connectionDidFinishLoading:]|182|Response:
    [DEBUG] 2013-12-01 23:25:17.841 Ti-AWS-S3[84675:a0b] AmazonS3Client.m|-[AmazonS3Client invoke:]|521|Response Status Code : 404
    [DEBUG] 2013-12-01 23:25:17.842 Ti-AWS-S3[84675:a0b] AmazonS3Client.m|-[AmazonS3Client invoke:]|530|Request threw exception: AmazonServiceException { RequestId:(null), ErrorCode:(null), Message:(null) }
    [DEBUG] 2013-12-01 23:25:17.842 Ti-AWS-S3[84675:a0b] AmazonS3Client.m|-[AmazonS3Client invoke:]|532|HTTP: 404, S3 Error Code: (null)
    [DEBUG] 2013-12-01 23:25:17.843 Ti-AWS-S3[84675:a0b] AmazonS3Client.m|-[AmazonS3Client invoke:]|534|Reason: (null)
```

as you can see, my callbacks are not fired.
is it something I am doing wrong? or is this a bug with the AWS SDK?

Comment: This looks like an uncaught exception in the S3TransferManager. As the S3TransferManager operates in a background thread, putting @try/@catch in your code doesn't help.

Comment: The particular code path you're hitting only occurs if the targetFilePath already exists on disk, so you should be able to work around this particular bug by making sure when downloading that the file doesn't exist locally first.

Comment: @BobKinney I am not sure this is the only case, but anyway what if the file exists but is partial? should I delete it first and forget about TransferManager ability to resume?

Comment: @BobKinney when you call it a 'bug', do you mean you this is a known issue with the AWS SDK ?

Comment: Based on your report, we are working on a fix. So yes, it is now a known issue. The particular uncaught exception you are seeing only occurs if the local file is present but the key has been removed from the S3 bucket.  

The S3TransferManager does a HEAD on the object to determine the size and try to find the MD5 of the file for comparison with the local.  This call fails which causes an exception to be thrown (if enabled).

Comment: @BobKinney are you sure that is the case? I asked for a file called NDAb.pdf, which does not exist in the bucket and never did, that is the reason it is also not present in the local folder, so this is not a case of a file existing and thus throwing an exception. in fact, the problem is the other way(!), with shouldNotThrowExceptions activated, there is no return value, no callback called, the app has no way to know the request failed because of a simple file not found error... thoughts?

Comment: I'm fairly confident in the statement. You can see in the [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/src/Amazon.S3/Model/S3GetObjectOperation_Internal.m#L109) that the metadata collection doesn't get called unless the local file is present. The lack of return may result in a 0-length file being generated which would cause the exception I'm mentioning. We have a fix in place and the only way I could generate the exception was if the file was already present on the device.

Comment: I did another test and your assumption is correct, I had a file like that locally from a previous test. this is the bug. when will the fix be available ?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot commit to a timeline other than to say that we hope to release it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We released version 1.7.1 of the AWS SDK for iOS that includes a couple of fixes related to S3TransferManager, including the issue you noted here.  You can read more about the other feature enhancements and bug fixes in [the release note](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/SDKs/iOS/3883528171209992).